# V$TRANSACTION table to find the duration of transactions

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find the names of transactions that have been active for more than 30 minutes from the current time using the START_TIME column of V$TRANSACTION table in Oracle?

Comment: Are you looking for sys.dm_exec_requests:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql

Comment: I am working with Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do arithmetic with dates in Oracle. Sysdate is the current datetime. There are 48 half-hours in a day. So:

```
select * 
from V$TRANSACTION
where to_date(start_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <= sysdate - (1/48)
```

Hmmm, it seems slightly odd that `V$TRANSACTION.start_time` uses a different format mask from sysdate. Anyway, you can avoid the ORA-01843 error with an explicit date conversion.

Comment: when I run this query ora-01843: not a valid month error occurs; this is because of different date-time formats, sysdate uses dd.mm.yyyy, whereas start_time works with mm/dd/yyyy). is there a way to modify the output of any of them?